# Structure map HttpSessionLifecycle object serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session, serialization, structuremap

I am using [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) to store a session object:

```
config.For<SessionContext>().LifecycleIs(new HttpSessionLifecycle());
```

And everything works okay, so I can easy retrieve the session object with [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

But now I need to switch my session from in-process to the database, but I receive the following error.

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode. --->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'StructureMap.Pipeline.MainObjectCache' in Assembly 'StructureMap,
>   Version=2.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223' is
>   not marked as serializable.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why minus? Anyone can explain?

Comment: Is every object in session marked as `[Serializable]`?

Comment: @Jay: Yeah, all my classes `Serializable`. Problem in structure map, it somehow wrap session object with his classes that's can't be serialized, see error above.

Comment: Why do you want the session context in your container? You are trying to store the session in the session - that seems wrong to me. If you explain your need, I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: @JoshuaFlanagan: I am not trying to store session in the session. My class `SessionContext` contains just simple properties (int, string). And i am trying to store it in a session through structure map HttpSessionLifecycle. And everything work's okay if session in memory. But when i trying to store session in a database (session items should be serializable) i receive above error. It seems that structure map wrap session items.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I assumed SessionContext was one of the many ASP.NET MVC *Context objects. Sounds like a StructureMap bug.

Comment: @JoshuaFlanagan: BTW, i am doing same thing in Unity 2.0 in another project and it's work. What do you think about fix/solution for this.

Comment: I imagine its not a difficult fix. Hopefully just a matter of adding [Serializable] onto a class (MainObjectCache) and testing it out. If you submit a pull request, I'll merge it in.

Comment: @JoshuaFlanagan: I've added [Serializable] attribute to MainObjectCache class and some others and tested it out. It work now. Will wait for structure map build with these changes. Let me know when you will do this to close this topic.

Comment: Thanks, I've pulled in your change (and a few others) and pushed a 2.6.3 release. Edit your answer to say it was a bug fixed in 2.6.3 and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in StructureMap. I've added the [Serializable] attribute to the `MainObjectCache` class and some others and tested it out. It works now. The fix can be found in [this](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/pull/22) pull request.

I hope @Joshua Flanagan will merge these changes into the master branch soon and the problem will be finally solved.

**Edit:**

> Thanks, I've pulled in your change (and a few others) and pushed a
>   2.6.3 release. Edit your answer to say it was a bug fixed in 2.6.3 and
>   mark it as the accepted answer. – Joshua Flanagan